# Операции с элементами списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, надо провести какие-нибудь математические операции, объединяющие все элементы списка в одно общее значение, и при этом отбросить некорректные значения.

Почему вот такой код работает некорректно (интересует именно момент проверки на число **isdigit ()** )?:

```
def sum_array(array):

    summ = 0

    for number in array:
        if number.isdigit ():
            summ += number
    return summ
```

[image: скрин с ошибкой]

Comment: `str.isdigit()` - эта функция возвращает `true`, если все `символы в строке` являются цифрами, и есть по крайней мере один символ, иначе `false`.

Comment: "Не работает" - не говорите, так пожалуйста! Смысл размазан, страшно представить. "На вход подаю конкретный список, а на выходе получаю не то, что ожидаю (входные данные, ожидания и реальность приложил в вопрос)" - вот так гораздо лучше. А то, что вы написали - вообще не понятно.

Comment: И вы понимаете, что между isdigit и скобками нет пробела?

Comment: @strawdog, да в общем то без разницы, обычный ворнинг на это выдается, но код работать не перестает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в том что `isdigit` это метод **строки**, а вы передаёте список **числе**. надо использовать функцию `isinstance`

```
if isinstance(number, int):
```

если надо чтобы программа работала с дробными числами то так:

```
if isinstance(number, (float, int)):
```

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу @DGDays:

для чисел:

```
arr = ['654','abc','456']
res = sum(int(elem) for elem in arr if elem.isdigit())
print(res)
```

для строк:

```
arr = ['654','abc','456']
res = ''.join(elem for elem in arr if elem.isdigit())
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю что именно вы имели ввиду, но всё работает -_-

Единственная проблема - если вы хотите получить в сумме целое число, то надо делать примерно так:

```
array = ['654','abc','456']
summ = 0
for number in array:
    if number.isdigit():
        summ += int(number)
print(summ)
```

Иначе, если нужна строка, то так:

```
array = ['654','abc','456']
summ = ''
for number in array:
    if number.isdigit():
        summ += number
print(summ)
```

Comment: Дополнил тело вопроса